# Vue Js Mounted did not triggred onpage load

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Not sure the reason why mounted is no triggered any function in it. tested by display 'ss' also cannot be print out when page is loaded.

```
export default {
  name: 'loads',
  components: {
    Overlay,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      subscribed: true,
    };
  },
computed: {
    filteredLocation() {
      return this.$store.getters['location/filterLocation'](this.searchTerm);
    },
  },
  methods: {
    checkSubscriptionValidity() {
      this.$store.dispatch('user/checkTrial').then((res) => {
        this.subscribed = res.data;
      });
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('ss');
    this.checkSubscriptionValidity();
  },
};
```

is there any other reason that can cause this mounted not triggered issues?

Comment: no errors? could you show us some more code

Comment: @Ifaruki yes no error. but the mounted is not triggered. i have edit the code and add whole script

Comment: this is a component i guess. so where do you import the component?

Comment: try created() hook. If it is not called than see where are you rendering this component.

Comment: @Ifaruki, it's a parent component where route from App.vue. other Vue file routes is functioning well with mounted(). just this file the mounted hook is not triggered

Comment: @AtifZia tried created() hook also before but seems not working also. this is a parent component.

Comment: also didn't seems like router problems. i tried to change them with other views routes but still this file did not triggered the mounted hook

Comment: I see no reason why the mounted hook should not be invoked.  Could you confirm that the component is being mounted. Please check your router file. Also, @Thái Bùi Minh posted an answer with an image showing that the mounted hook is being invoked. Please respond to his answer.

Comment: try change in its template part and see affects are shown or not?

Comment: @AtifZia , i have change the whole template to just display text also no effect

Comment: Than it is clear you are not rendering component rightly.

Comment: @AtifZia i don't know why. i'm creating a new file and copy the same code in it. and it's just work. is it because file name? before this the name is location

Comment: maybe it is possibly file name issue. However I am not sure about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this syntax:

```
  computed: {
    filteredLocation: () => {
      return this.$store.getters['location/filterLocation'](this.searchTerm);
    },
  },
  methods: {
    checkSubscriptionValidity: () => {
      this.$store.dispatch('user/checkTrial').then((res) => {
        this.subscribed = res.data;
      });
    },
  },
  mounted: () => {
    console.log('ss');
    this.checkSubscriptionValidity();
  },
```

[image]

Comment: i'm sorry but it's doesn't affect by mounted hook. it's same by using function () methods

Comment: Please see my attached image :D

Comment: still it not triggered / invoke the mounted hook

Comment: Do you try again? I updated the following code and please see my attached image carefully. :D

Comment: yes i tried, but i know this code works same with mines. i've solve this with changing file naming. i'm not sure if it's because naming location.vue early that cause this issues. but sure i can mark as accepted answer for other person reference